# Angular : know if components are loaded in a service

Tags: angular

In an Angular project, I try to append some elements in my DOM after redirecting a user to a route thanks to the navigateByUrl() method.

My problem is that I need to wait all components view to be loaded in the DOM before to append my elements (cause they are dynamically append to DOM element queried by ("[data-mydata]") which can be in many components).

For now, I use something like:

```
this.router.navigateByUrl('myurl').then(() => { setTimeout(() => { appendElements() }, 1000)}
```

but it is clearly imprecise.

My code is written in a service and so I don't know how to wait components loading or to check if components are loaded.

Have you some ideas to do that?

Comment: So basically you want your components to tell the service that they're done loading and execute some function when that happens?

Comment: What appendElements function actually does?

Comment: Yes @MikeS. basically it could works, but if it is possible to not necessary write code in all components that could be impacts by the function appendElements it could be better. Like that my code could be transparent for other development in future

Comment: There's no way to do that, your service does not know of the components that consume it and thus, can't precisely say when they're done loading. You'll have to have each component set some flag in your service and check if every flag is set everytime you set one flag. If all are set, you can run your function. To be even more precise, you would set this flag during `ngAfterContentInit` or `ngAfterViewInit`.

Comment: @Nikolay The function appendElements get a collection of all DOM elements with attribute "data-mydata" (document.querySelectorAll("data-mydata")). Then the foreach function is used on this collection to instanciate a component and display its view in the DOM after each HTMLElement of the collection.

Comment: Ok @MikeS., that's what I was afraid of, thanks anyway. I am not sure that I need to create a new post for this, but here I use the Router service to redirect my user, so is there an event or an observable to know, after redirection, that view has been loaded? That might be enough in my case.

Comment: The available events can be found here https://angular.io/api/router/Event, you can subscribe to them in your service and react to them using `if(event instanceof NavigationEnd) // do stuff`. I doubt that's late enough for the components to already be done loading, but it might be worth a try

Comment: @ayolyan you could try to create directive with a selector [data-mydata] 
Please check this - [https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-bxlgia](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-bxlgia?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcustom.directive.ts) I suppose that this appendElements function is using some external js library to append new elements in the DOM, so you should extract the body of the foreach loop and put it into the directive constructor thereby there is no need to be aware of all elements with data-mydata attribute and theirs existence on the page.

Comment: Thanks again @MikeS. Indeed, that's not late enough for the components to already be done loading. I am going to try others solutions like the one of Nikolay

Comment: Thank you @Nikolay your smart idea is perfect. It does exactly what I want doing!